# How many subsets of $ A $ contain odd numbers?

Tags: proof-verification, arithmetic

Let $ A $ be the set formed by the $ n $ terms of the arithmetic progression given by
$$ \begin {cases}
a_1 = 1 \\
r = 1 \\
\end {cases} $$Knowing that $ med (A) $ does not belong to $ A $, how many subsets of $ A $ contain odd numbers?

Note: $ med (A) $ represents the statistical median of the values of $ A $

Solution: The progression is just $1, 2, \dots, n,$ which does not contain the median $(1+n)/2$ iff $n$ is even. Letting $n = 2k,$ the possible subsets are subsets of $\{1, 3, \dots, 2k-1\}$ for a total of $2^k = 2^{n/2}$ possible subsets.

Correct?

Comment: Do you mean sets which "contain **only** odd numbers", or "contains **at least one** odd number"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2^{2k}$ subsets of $A$, and there are $2^k$ subsets of $A$ which contain only even numbers (and hence which do *not* contain odd numbers).

It follows that there are $2^{2k}-2^k = 2^k(2^k-1)$ subsets of $A$ which contain at least one odd number.

(Do you now understand where your solution went wrong? You calculated the number of subsets $A$ which contain *only* odd numbers.)

Comment: To be fair the verb "contains" and "contains odd numbers" is unclear.  Interpreting it as containing only odd numbers is understandable.....  Tim asks "What's in the bag?". Jane answers "Bananas".  Tim reaches in and pulls out an apple "Hey, I thought you said the bag contains bananas".  Jane says "It does; just reach under the potatoes and next to the cans of tomato soup; there's a bunch with three bananas on it."

Comment: I agree it could have been more explicitly worded. In mathematical problems, I tend to favor the set theoretic interpretation of 'contain', like in mathematical problems I tend to favor the logical interpretation of 'or'. But actual linguistic meaning has these pitfalls.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "How many contain..." in mathematics should always be interpretted to many "how many contain at least one"  (and "how many contain one..." should be interpreted as "how many contain one or more...").  But it's not that the OP did anything "wrong".... just that the OP interpreted it one way that was probably not the intent.